What can be deduced about a complex function from its abolute square and the abolute square of its Fourier transform?
Problem definition
Suppose we have a function $\psi(x),\psi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$. It represents a probability amplitude so we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\left|\psi(x)\right|}^2dx = 1.$$
Let's define its Fourier transform as $\phi(f), \phi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$. It can be expressed as
$$\phi(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)e^{-i2\pi fx}dx.$$
Say we are given only the absolute square of $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(f)$. What can we say about the probability amplitudes?
My initial attempt
We can express $\psi(x)$ as a real function $\psi_r(x)$ multiplied by a varying phase shift
$$\psi(x) = \psi_r(x) e^{i 2\pi \theta(x)}.$$
The phase shift is controlled by $\theta(x)$. This way $\psi_r(x)$ is entirely determined by the known absolute square of $\psi(x)$. The phase shift on the other hand is independent. I'm hoping the absoute square of $\phi(k)$ will provide some constraints for it. $\phi(f)$ can also be written in the following form then
$$\phi(f) = F\left[\psi_r(x)\right]*F\left[e^{i 2\pi\theta(x)}\right],$$
where $F[-]$ denotes the Fourier transform and $*$ denotes convolution.
This is as far as I've got. I tried taking the absolute square, but I couldn't solve for the phase shift $\theta(x)$. I don't expect to be able to determine $\theta(x)$ uniquely in general. I also expect that for certain combinations of the given absolute squares no $\theta(x)$ will exist.
I'm mainly interested in the following:

Can we determine whether a $\theta(x)$ exists for given absolute squares?
Can we solve for $\theta(x)$ if it exists?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

$\psi(x)=| \psi(x)|,  e^{i, \arg(\psi(x))}$, but your question is not clear to me. Perhaps the Plancherel theorem provides some insight. If you're given $\phi(k)$, you can derive $\psi(x)$ via the inverse Fourier transform.

Added the $2\pi$ so we don't need to worry about that. Yes the Fourier transform of the convolution between two function becomes the product of the Fourier transformed factors. It works the other way around too as far as I understand. The Fourier transform of a product is the convolution between the Fourier transformed factors, which is what I stated.

This reminds me of an old question on physics SE that I gave some thought 11 years ago: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/81542/25794 (in the comments it was conjectured that the full wave function could be reconstructed up to time reversal (complex conjugation)

Given $\phi(f)$ an inverse transform would be enough, but the problem statement was that we're only given the absolute squares of $\psi$ and $\phi$. Plancherel's theorem creates a connection between the given absolute squares, but I don't think it help determining $\psi$ and $\phi$. Of course the given absolute squares have to be compatible with the theorem.

@doetoe: that link is pure gold. Thank you very much. I like that discussion and your answer a lot.

Thanks @doetoe. I'll check the link. To be honest that's the motivation behind the question. I'm learning QM and I was wondering if the full wave function could be restored from position and momentum measurements. It has to be possible, right? Otherwise how could it be possible to predict anything that could involve interference?

Your question stated "absolute square of $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(f)$" which I interpreted as your first two formulas. If $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\left|\psi(x)\right|}^2 , dx=1$$ then$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\left|\phi(f)\right|}^2 , dx=1$$ by the Plancherel theorem. But these integrals don't provide any information on ${\left|\psi(x)\right|}^2$ or ${\left|\phi(f)\right|}^2$ at specific values of $x$ or $f$, and there are many $L_2$ (square-integrable) functions (possibly infinite) where the integral evaluates to $1$.

So you mean you are given formulas for evaluating ${\left|\psi(x)\right|}^2$ and ${\left|\phi(f)\right|}^2$ in addition to the square-integrable value?

Yes, $\left|\psi(x)\right|^2$ and $\left|\phi(x)\right|^2$ are given. What can we determine about $\psi$ and $\phi$?

My first formula is the integral of the absolute square of $\psi$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. You're absolutely right about Plancherel theorem and what that tells us about the integral of the absolute square of $\psi$.

The answers at the physics StackExchange question linked in a comment above seem to answer your question, but why $\left|\psi(x)\right|^2$ and $\left|\phi(x)\right|^2$ instead of just $\left|\psi(x)\right|$ and $\left|\phi(x)\right|$?

I don't think it makes a difference. The absolute values could be given instead. The answers at the linked question gave me lots of insight. I still want to keep the question open as the answers don't fully address the problem in my opinion. @doetoe Correct me if I'm wrong, but the dimensional analysis only restricts the possible combinations of given absolute squares, it doesn't say anything about the possibility of extracting the phase.

The argument involving time reversal symmetry makes sense physically. I specifically wanted to keep QM out of this question, because it is more general. There's no time dependence. The symmetry is still there, but I'd like to restate that argument in a form that doesn't involve time. The most interesting part was the fixed point algorithm which I'm definitely going to try, but I'm looking for analytical statements. I saw the specific example about the Gaussian. I've also experimented with it. I'll extend the question with a summary of all this.

I was thinking $\left|\psi(x)\right|$ looks simpler than $\left|\psi(x)\right|^2$, but I realized perhaps the reason is that for complex numbers its an extra step to compute $\left|\psi(x)\right|$. I'm wondering if progress can be made with additional information like whether $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are even or odd functions or whether they're strictly real or strictly imaginary. Also, it might not be practical, but are you assuming for example that one can theoretically determine all of the zeros and poles of $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ from $\left|\psi(x)\right|^2$ and $\left|\phi(x)\right|^2$.

It'd be helpful to receive an explanation when the question gets closed. How would I make this more focused? This is what I'm looking for exactly. According to https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions I was supposed to receive private feedback, which I haven't.

@TamásSoós I think the questions is focused enough, but maybe it is not immediately clear what you're asking. The only thing I would change to make it clearer is to replace the last line of the question "Say we are given only the absolute squares of $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(f)$. What can we say about the probability amplitudes?" with "Say we are given only the absolute squares $|\psi|^2$ and $|\phi|^2$ of $\psi$ and $\phi$. What can we say about the function $\psi$?". Not sure that that is enough to get it reopened, but who knows.
